# Using PHP locally to send an email giving no error but no email received

Tags: php, email, localhost, wampserver

**EDIT**

I uncomment `sendmail_path` and set it as `sendmail_path = "sendmail -t -i"`. Now there is no error but no email received.

The port is 25, and tls://smtp.gmail.com is the server.

**END EDIT**

I need to send an email, locally, to an the admin, when a user request a new password. At the top of my `API.php` file, I have added the following `ini_set()` lines:

```
ini_set("SMTP","tls://smtp.gmail.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","587");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@YourDomain.com');
```

And also, I've changed the php.ini file to the same values:

```
mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = tls://smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from ="admin@wampserver.invalid"

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
```

The error I am having is:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "tls://smtp.gmail.com" port 587, verify your
>   "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
>   ini_set() in C:\wamp64\www\dev\api.php on line 165

I used the scripts at line 165 but still the same. I have openssl enabled as `echo phpinfo();` showed.

I changed the port to 25, with localhost as smtp, but still the same error.

The following didn't help me as it is giving me the same error message.

[First Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677350/how-to-send-smtp-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: try with port 465

Comment: The same error.

Comment: I would really recommend that you use one of the tried and tested high level mail libraries, like PHPMailer, SwiftMailer or similar instead of PHP's own low level API. It makes the code way more verbose. It will also make your code more portable (since it won't require any system configuration).

Comment: ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");  try to change like  this  instead of tls use ssl  with port 465 and then check

Comment: @suresh didn't work as well.

Comment: @Sinto I saw it and didn't work for me to sir.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp not sure about `tls://`

Comment: did you try changing this line SMTP = tls://smtp.gmail.com to SMTP = localhost

Comment: @suresh yes I did.

Comment: Yes I still have the same error

Comment: Check my edit in a minute guys

Comment: You can check my edits please.

Comment: did you set your to mail? i mean send_email path

Comment: Yeah, And that what made crazy about why not working.

Comment: ;sendmail_path = is this the one you have told you have set? try to Restart Wamp Server.

Comment: Yes I uncomment it and restart it, I think I will go for PHPMailer library instead.

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page, since that is also trying to send mail via GMail