# PHPMailer doesn't send mail even after including SMTP.php

Tags: php, mysql

For some strange reason my PHP login system that sends a confirmation email to activate your account but it doesn't send anything.

```
<?php
$error = NULL;
require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
require "phpmailer/class.smtp.php";
require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";



if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Form Data GET
    $u = $_POST['u'];
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $p2 = $_POST['p2'];
    $e = $_POST['e'];

    //Throw Username too short error
    if(strlen($u) < 5){
        $error = "(!) Your username must be at least 5 characters.";
    }elseif($p2 != $p) {
    //Throw password pair error.
        $error .= "(!) Your passwords do not match :/";
    }else{
        //200 [OK]

        //Establish Connection to Database
        $mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','test');
        //Convert special chars.
        $u = $mysqli->real_escape_string($u);
        $p = $mysqli->real_escape_string($p);
        $p2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($p2);
        $e = $mysqli->real_escape_string($e);

        //Generate Verification Key
        $vkey = md5(time().$u);

        //Insert account into database
        $p = md5($p);
        $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO accounts(username,password,email,vkey)
            VALUES('$u','$p','$e','$vkey')");

        if($insert){
            //Start PHPMailer
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;   //No Debug. Set to 3 for verbose logging.
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; //Set to SSL to pass checks.
            $mail->Host = "smtp.mail.com"; //Set to mail.com server, it has ssl, smtp, and it's free. If you'd like to use gmail, use smtp.gmail.com
            $mail->Port = 465;  //SSL/TLS Port for mail.com and gmail.com

            //FILL WITH YOUR DETAILS
            $mail->Username = 'example@mail.com';
            $mail->Password = 'example';

            //DON'T SET TO SENDER ADDRESS WILL FAIL SPF CHECKS!!!
            $mail->SetFrom('example@mail.com', 'example');
            $mail->AddAddress($e);

            //Send the email.
            $mail->Subject = trim("Email Verifcation");
            $mail->isHTML(true);

            //The Message
            $mail->Body = '<h1>Hi, ' . $u . '!</h1><br><p><a href="https://localhost' . $vkey . '">Activate</a><br><p>Alternatively copy and paste this link in your browser: <br> <b>Https://localhost' . $vkey . '';

            echo "<center><div class='alert success'><strong>Successfully Registered!</strong> Please check your email.</div></center>";


        }
        //OOPS! Throw $error.
            echo $mysqli->error;

    }


}


?>
```

In the beginning, I require the files in my PHPMailer folder, then I start PHPMailer

It stresses me out. Idk the problem. If anybody knows the solution or knows a hint of why it doesn't work that would be great. Thanks.
HTML in same file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <style>
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.alert.success {background-color: #4CAF50;}
.alert.info {background-color: #2196F3;}
.alert.warning {background-color: #ff9800;}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Username:</td>
    <td><input type="TEXT" name="u" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Password</td>
    <td><input type="PASSWORD" name="p" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Repeat Password</td>
    <td><input type="PASSWORD" name="p2" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Email Address</td>
    <td><input type="EMAIL" name="e" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Register" required/></td>
    </table>
    </form>   
    <center>
    <?php 
    echo $error ;
    ?>
    </center>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you update the Username and Password from the example values to use an actual email and password? You also need to do the same for whichever system you're sending through (for example Gmail).

Comment: yeah, it's the first thing I did. It's actually a school volunteer project. I added all the comments. Good Catch though. Let me add the HTML

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? I'd check there first to see if there are any errors thrown.

Comment: I would setDebug to verbose to see if there are errors

Comment: I'm on localhost and it doesn't display anything if I set it to verbose

Comment: Have you modified `php.ini`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677350/how-to-send-smtp-mail-from-localhost

Comment: Oh, thanks but actually I'm on a mac. So but actually plan to move it to a shared server

Comment: you're right im just gonna scrap everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can probably try this
i also had an error so i had to add this line before the host

```
$mail->SMTPOptions=array('ssl'=>array('verify_peer'=>false,'verify_peer_name'=>false,'allow_self_signed'=>false));
```

but if that does not work you can try trobleshooting like this

```
if($mail->Send()){ 



}else{ 

var_dump($mail);
die();

}
```

so once you get your error logs you can probably do a google or paste your error log and maybe we can help