# Error when setting SMTP server for php code igniter

Tags: php, smtp

```
 $config = [
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mail.xxxxx.it',
        'smtp_user' => 'notification@xxxxx.it',
        'smtp_pass' => 'sudwwualwor',
        'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'crlf' => "\r\n",
        'newline' => "\r\n"
    ];
```

i have setting up my smtp using php. but when i try this setting on my local xampp i got error like this

> "fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrInfo failed Not such host know"

if i ping my smtp_host i can get result success. i have question how to fix this issue ? on my server i use cpanel. but on my local i use xampp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677350/how-to-send-smtp-mail-from-localhost

Comment: `ssl://mail.xxxxx.it` - that is not a host name. The host name portion of that address is only `mail.xxxxx.it`

Comment: $config = [
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'mail.xxxxx.it',
        'smtp_user' => 'notification@xxxxx.it',
        'smtp_pass' => 'sudwwualwor',
        'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'crlf' => "\r\n",
        'newline' => "\r\n"
    ];  i have tried use this. i cannot found error but i cannot get email